# Access Memory with a pointer vs cv::Mat::at method

Tags: c++, opencv

After doing some research on the subject I thought that accessing the elements from a cv::Mat element would be faster than using at method (because apparently at checks for boundaries everytime and makes multiplications if I understood correctly) !

Though, i wrote a little test and using at seems to be about 1000 times faster everytime :/ ! So i guess i'm doing something wrong but i can't figure out what ..

There is my piece of code :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int k = 0;

int size[] = {100, 100};

cv::Mat image(2, size, CV_32SC1, cv::Scalar::all(0));

for (int i = 0; i < size[0]; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < size[1]; j++) {
    image.at<int>(i, j) = k;
    k++;
  }
}

int *myval;

int width = image.cols;
int height = image.rows;

myval = image.ptr<int>(0);
int val;

double t = (double)cv::getTickCount();
for (int i = 0; i < height*width; i++) {
    val = myval[i];
}
t = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - t) / cv::getTickFrequency();
std::cout << "time ptr : " << t << std::endl;

t = (double)cv::getTickCount();
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    val = image.at<int>(i, j);
  }
}
t = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - t) / cv::getTickFrequency();
std::cout << "time without ptr : " << t << std::endl;
```

}

So basically, it just acces every element of my matrix once and do nothing.
Though i get these kind of results :

```
time ptr : 0.00017332
time without ptr : 2.77e-07
```

or

```
time ptr : 4.0991e-05
time without ptr : 7.6e-08
```

If someone could give me some explainations or new ideas that would be really cool !

Thank you all :)

Comment: I would use a much larger image size to test and `std::chrono` instead to time. Also your code could be optimized out since you do nothing with the val. A smart compiler/optimizer could determine there is no point of your loops at all.

Comment: Yes in fact in a first time i was trying to improve a function that i wrote using pointer instead of at method but i realized i was way slower with my pointer so i just created this little useless program to test only the access to the memory and compare. 
I just tried with a bigger image (10000x10000) but the result still tell me that time with ptr is greater than time without pointer :/

Comment: Did you do something with `val` in your larger example? Perhaps just summing the pixel values.

Comment: Yes i changed and i do :

    val += image.at<int>(i, j);

&

    val += myval[i];

I also took your advice and use std::chrono !

But still same result :/

Comment: Not sure if the benchmark is correct (it is not easy to write a correct benchmark). What is the result with? `for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    val = image.ptr<int>(i)[j];
  }
}`

Comment: Ok I tried that ! But even if it is better than my "time with pointer", it still is generally slower than the Mat::cv::at method !

In order to make a more precise measurement, I make the measure 500 times and I take the mean.

The results are :

   Time with ptr : 2.3308e-08
   Time without ptr : 2.3192e-08
   Time with ptr Catree : 2.3202e-08

Comment: @A.Piro So now you get almost the same execution time for all the methods? I don't think the benchmark is meaningful. In my opinion, the difference could be due to anything: a slight CPU overload (there are multiple processes run at the same time on a modern OS), different scheduling, CPU Turbo Boost, etc.

Comment: Mmh I think I see what you mean ! You're probably right ! Is there a way to tackle these kind of problem except by restarting the computer ?